# PHP MySQL JSON Query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having trouble querying MySQL5.7.x JSON data.

I have the following JSON stored in the field `activities`.  I want to search for activities where the outcome_id = 418

My table has one record with `student_id` field with value of 10 and the `activities` field.

```
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "activity": "Quiz from pages 100-102",
      "comments": "comments",
      "outcomes": [
        {
          "outcome_id": "418",
          "course": "English",
          "course_level": "2"
        },
        {
          "outcome_id": "419",
          "course": "English",
          "course_level": "2"
        },
        {
          "outcome_id": "420",
          "course": "English",
          "course_level": "2"
        },
        {
          "outcome_id": "600",
          "course": "Science",
          "course_level": "2"
        }
      ],
      "date_completed": "20180102"
    },
    {
      "activity": "Quiz from pages 200-250",
      "comments": "comments",
      "outcomes": [
        {
          "outcome_id": "518",
          "course": "English",
          "course_level": "2"
        },
        {
          "outcome_id": "519",
          "course": "English",
          "course_level": "2"
        }
      ],
      "date_completed": "20180102"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following PHP code but I am getting no results.

```
$query = ("SELECT 


    activities->'$.activities[*].activity'

    FROM table WHERE

    JSON_EXTRACT(activities, '$.activities[*].outcomes[*].outcome_id')  = '\"418\"' AND student_id = '10'
    ");
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried not adding double quotes to `418`?

Comment: Is your desired output only the activity which has an `outcome_id` of 418 i.e. `"Quiz from pages 100-102"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that the desired output from this query is `"Quiz from pages 100-102"`.

Your query doesn't work as you think: `JSON_EXTRACT` will return an array of all `outcome_id`'s using the path you specified (in this case, `["418", "419", "420", "600", "518", "519"]`). You can use `JSON_SEARCH` to find only the activities which have an `outcome_id` of 418 like so:

```
JSON_SEARCH(activities, 'all', '418', NULL, '$.activities[*].outcomes[*].outcome_id')
```

which will return a string value of `"$.activities[0].outcomes[0].outcome_id"` but there isn't any way I can think of to get the `[0]` index of activities into your `SELECT` where you really want `SELECT activities->'$.activities[0].activity'`.

Overall, I don't think you can achieve this using the built-in MySQL JSON functions without going to a stored procedure. Your best strategy would be to use

```
SELECT activities FROM table WHERE student_id = 10
```

and post-process the result in your PHP (I'm assuming you decode the JSON into a variable called `$json`):

```
$selected = array();
foreach ($json->activities as $activity) {
    foreach ($activity->outcomes as $outcome) {
        if ($outcome->outcome_id == '418') $selected[] = $activity->activity;
    }
}
print_r($selected);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Quiz from pages 100-102
)
```

Comment: Yes, the desired output from this query is "Quiz from pages 100-102".   I guess I will have to load the entire JSON document for a student and process the JSON in PHP

Comment: If there was a way that you could get individual activities in the database (rather than the activities array you have at the moment) you could make it work in MySQL using the `JSON_SEARCH` I mentioned.